# I am trying to decipher some terminal code

Tags: command-line

What does `-a` and `-G` mean? Thanks.

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data username
```

Comment: If you type `usermod --help` in terminal, you get some basic description of commands options. If you type `man usermod` you get a more detailed description. You can also [find it online here](http://linux.die.net/man/8/usermod).

Answer (score 3):

From `man usermod`:

```
   -a, --append
       Add the user to the supplementary group(s). Use only with the -G option.

   -G, --groups GROUP1[,GROUP2,...[,GROUPN]]]
       A list of supplementary groups which the user is also a member of. Each group is separated from the next by a comma, with no
       intervening whitespace. The groups are subject to the same restrictions as the group given with the -g option.

       If the user is currently a member of a group which is not listed, the user will be removed from the group. This behaviour can be
       changed via the -a option, which appends the user to the current supplementary group list.
```

In short, `sudo usermod -aG www-data username` adds the `username` user to the `www-data` group.

Comment: Thanks. You mind telling me where I can find a list of all these types of commands. I searched, but could only find a list of basic commands.

Comment: Personally, I try `man command-of-interest` or `command-of-interest --help` first.